# Function inside function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function, which has a function inside it. Why does this code not work? It has to look like this, because I've created a XMLHttpRequest inside getNumber(). The code below is just an example.

```
getNumber();

function getNumber()
{
    otherFunction = function()
    {
        console.log("It's working!");
    }
}
```

Comment: **what** doesn't work? And does it not work?

Comment: @Thomas It does not output "It's working!". So basically the code insite 'otherFunction' doesn't work.

Comment: you've created `otherFunction`, but you never call it

Comment: @Thomas Because this is an example, I've created a XMLHttpRequest. I use 'request.onload = function()'. I can't call 'request();' later.

Comment: Then please use an example that properly represents and replicates what you're doing/your problem. Have you considered that there's an error with your ajax request (maybe something serverside, maybe a timeout, ...), and that the onerror handler is called instead of onload?

Comment: Try using the request.onload = function followed by request.send()

Comment: I've already found a solution, I used callback instead of return and it worked.

Comment: @XenzLSD, this makes no sense whatsoever in the context of the question that you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

It does "work" (well, so long as you aren't using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) — always use strict mode! — since it depends on implicit globals).

You call `getNumber`, which defines a global variable called `otherFunction` and uses a function expression to assign a value to it.

If you ever called `otherFunction` (**you don't!**), it would log *It's working*.

As it stands, nothing in your code should generate any output.

```js
getNumber();

function getNumber()
{
    otherFunction = function()
    {
        console.log("It's working!");
    }
}

otherFunction();
```

Comment: How can I do it when it's a XMLHttpRequest? I use 'request.onload = function()' I can't call 'request();' in the code.

Comment: @XenzLSD — If you do that then it will be called when (and if) the load event fires. If it doesn't get called, then the request is not getting a successful response.

Comment: I've already found a solution, I used callback instead of return and it worked.